# OpenInventor components in Coin

Tags: openinventor, coin3d

I am presently evaluating OpenInventor for the purpose of building a 3d application that should have small windows through which a user can made edits to objects in a scenegraph. Pages 35-[37](http://www.fit.vutbr.cz/%7Epeciva/Mentor.pdf#page=37) of the "Inventor Mentor" (IM) contains screenshots of such small windows and controls, which -- from what I can see in chapter 16 -- are called *components*.

[image: Screenshot of application on page 37 of the Inventor Mentor.]

The problem is that the OpenInventor implementation that I have access to ([coin](https://github.com/coin3d/coin)) does not implement an abstract base class for components (c.f. [SoXtComponent](https://www.openinventor.com/reference-manuals/NewRefMan9912/RefManCpp/class_so_xt_component.html)), therefore most of the IM examples shipped with the Coin3d Python wrapper fail to run and produce errors such as:

```
The SoGuiMaterialEditor node has not been implemented in the SoGui bindings of Coin!
```

Is there any way to emulate components in coin? I would like to use coin because its Python binding ([pivy](https://github.com/coin3d/pivy)) is the reason I chose coin in the first place, or is [soxt](https://github.com/coin3d/soxt/tree/master) my only option?

**Update**

Rummaging through my site packages and I found a shared object that contains a promising `SoQtComponent`, <s>which I do not yet know how to instantiate</s>.

```
nm -D _soqt.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so | grep Component | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 3 | c++filt 
SoQtComponent::initClasses()
SoQtComponent::getComponent(QWidget*)
SoQtComponent::setIconTitle(char const*)
SoQtComponent::setFullScreen(int)
SoQtComponent::getClassTypeId()
SoQtComponent::setWidgetCursor(QWidget*, SoQtCursor const&)
SoQtComponent::setWindowCloseCallback(void (*)(void*, SoQtComponent*), void*)
SoQtComponent::setSize(SbVec2s)
SoQtComponent::setTitle(char const*)
SoQtComponent::initClass()
SoQtComponent::isVisible()
SoQtComponent::getClassName() const
SoQtComponent::getIconTitle() const
SoQtComponent::isFullScreen() const
SoQtComponent::getBaseWidget() const
SoQtComponent::getWidgetName() const
SoQtComponent::getShellWidget() const
SoQtComponent::getParentWidget() const
SoQtComponent::isTopLevelShell() const
SoQtComponent::getSize() const
SoQtComponent::getTitle() const
SoQtComponent::getWidget() const
```

**Update 2**

I now know how to import the `SoQtComponent`, so I guess I have the answer??

```py
from pivy.gui.soqt import SoQtComponent
```